# List of Hashmap in one to many relationships

Tags: java, jpa, dictionary, one-to-many

I have 2 tables with relationship of one-to-many. What I need to do is to categorize the sub-table (many part) into some categories and display them. So for example, I have a region and product table. so one region will have many products, but there are many products that belong to a specific category and I am going to display them all into one section.
So what I want is something like:

```
@Entity
public class Region {

    // ... some codes here
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<HashMap<Long, List<Product>>> ProductEntities;
    // ... some codes here
}
```

any suggestions please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I am doing. But appreciate if get a better solution.

```
@Entity
public class Region {

    // ... some codes here
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Product> ProductEntities;

    @Transient
    private HashMap<Long, List<Product>> productsMap;

    public HashMap<Long, List<Product>> getProductsMap() {
        if (ProductEntities!= null) {
            for (Product product : ProductEntities) {
                List<Product> productList = productsMap.get(product.getProductTypeEntity().getId());
                if (productList == null) {
                    productList= new ArrayList<Product>();
                }
                productList.add(product);
                productsMap.put(product.getProductTypeEntity().getId(), productList);
            }
        }
        return productsMap;
    }

    // ... rest of codes
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to do the relational model first, map to JPA and then make a query with group by.

Let suppose the following model:

```
+--------+    /+---------+\    +----------+
| Region |-----| Product |-----| Category |
+--------+    \+---------+/    +----------+
```

The query could be like this:

```
select r.region_name, c.category_name, p.product_name
from Product p
join p.region r
join p.category c
group by r.region_name, c.category_name, p.product_name
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. but that doesn't solve my problem. First of all I am limited to `r.region_name, c.category_name, p.product_name` which is because of nature of group by. Second, I will get them as list, which again I should have a mechanism in UI to differentiate the categories (In my case, it is not just displaying. The order is defined in UI in a specific manner)